# Read fom CSV and store data to ArrayList

Tags: java, android, csv, arraylist, opencsv

I am using OpenCSV to read a CSV file stored in the internal storage of the device at `\G Shop\Input CSV\` named `product.csv`. The file contains a single column of some random product names. I want to store each product into an `ArrayList` but my code is not working.

Here's the code:

```
String baseDirectory = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
File readCsvFolder = new File(baseDirectory + File.separator + "G Shop" + File.separator + "Input CSV" + File.separator);
String readFileName;
String readFilePath;
List<String[]> readData;

void readCSV() {
    readCsvFolder.mkdirs();

    readFileName = "products.csv";
    readFilePath = readCsvFolder.getPath() + File.separator + readFileName;
    try {
        ArrayList<String> searchProducts = new ArrayList<>();

        readData = new ArrayList<String[]>();
        CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(readFilePath));
        readData = reader.readAll();

        String[] row;
        while ((row = reader.readNext()) != null) {
            searchProducts.add(row[0]);

            //This Toast never shows up!
            Toast.makeText(mainActContext,"Saved : " + row[0],Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I see no errors or warnings, there is simply no output after the method is called. I would highly appreciate any sort of help or suggestions :)

Comment: what's: readData = reader.readAll(); all data have been loaded by it?

Comment: @user3380739 Yep, that was what was causing the issue.
After removing that line the code ran perfectly.
BTW, sorry for the late reply, I've been a little busy lately and also thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

`readData = reader.readAll();` Is reading the entire file input stream until end of file. Thus `row = reader.readNext()) != null` is going to give you nothing from the get go; the reader has already reached the end of the file. Instead your loop could simply be: `for(String[] row:readData)`:

```
for(String[] row:readData) {
    searchProducts.add(row[0]);

    //Now the toast shows up!
    Toast.makeText(mainActContext,"Saved : " + row[0],Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```